# Simulating rigid body collisions in 3d

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, computational-physics, simulations, rigid-body-dynamics, solid-mechanics

I have been reading about physics engines and I am confused on how one approaches simulating collision responses.

I read about the coefficient of restitution:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coefficient_of_restitution

But it wasn't clear how this idea could be extended to 3d with rigid bodies. Conceptually you could make contacts non-hard and integrate a force + damping term over a number of iterations dependent upon penetration depth but that is not how engines with hard contact constraints work which is what I am interested in.

Comment: Is this physics engine constraint-based, and is it force-based or impulse-based? Collisions can be implemented as inequality constraints and solved in the usual manner.

Comment: Try to have a look at the Ten Minute Physics channel on yt https://youtube.com/@TenMinutePhysics

Comment: I am interested in the impulse based formulation but even force based would be interesting.

Comment: What does "making contacts non-hard" mean (as opposed to "hard contact constraints")?

Comment: It means your rebound force would be some function of penetration depth.

Comment: Have you looked at something like [this](https://box2d.org/files/ErinCatto_UnderstandingConstraints_GDC2014.pdf)?

Comment: Yes, what is unclear to me is how you compute collision impulses/forces when you have multiple moving objects so there will be a bounce between them.

Comment: The formulas with restitution are also spelt out explicitly [here](https://nkarve.github.io/programming/2021/07/02/physeng4.html).

Comment: I'm not understanding how angular inertia is taken into account, for example if you have two rotating masses one much bigger than the other, after collision the rotation of the big one won't be changed much but the little one will spin a different direction.

Comment: Related [post](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/744349/392)

Comment: Look at this [2D example](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/743864/collision-with-extended-bodies/743882#743882) and this [3D answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/732131/are-there-any-conditions-to-apply-coefficient-of-restitution-in-rotational-and-a/732202#732202)

Comment: The canonical way is to read the [Physically Based Modeling](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~baraff/sigcourse/) lecture notes I, and II.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In all three scenarios of two particles, a particle and a 3D body and two 3D bodies the calculation of the impulse magnitude $J$ is the same, once the *reduced mass* $m^\star$ of the contact is found.

$$ \boxed{ J = (1+\epsilon)\, m^\star \; v_{\rm imp}} $$

where $v_{\rm imp}$ is the relative speed of approach of the two bodies at the point of contact, $\epsilon$ is the coefficient of restitution and $m^\star$ is the reduced mass of the system.

For the three cases above, this is how to calculate the reduced mass given the contact normal direction $\boldsymbol{n}$.

- **Two Particles** of mass $m_1$ and $m_2$

  $$ m^\star = \dfrac{1}{\frac{1}{m_1} + \frac{1}{m_2}} $$
- **One Body and One Particle** with masses $m_1$ and $m_2$ respectively, and mass moment of inertia tensor ${\bf I}_1$ for the body, as well as the position of the center of mass, relative to the contact point, denoted with the vector $\boldsymbol{d}_1$

  $$ m^\star = \dfrac{1}{\frac{1}{m_1} + ( \boldsymbol{n}\times \boldsymbol{d}_1) \cdot {\bf I}_1^{-1} (\boldsymbol{n} \times \boldsymbol{d}_1) + \frac{1}{m_2}} $$
- **Two Bodies** with masses $m_1$ and $m_2$ respectively, and mass moment of inertia tensor ${\bf I}_1$ and ${\rm I}_2$, as well as the positions of the center of mass, relative to the contact point, denoted with the vectors $\boldsymbol{d}_1$ and $\boldsymbol{d}_2$

  $$ m^\star = \dfrac{1}{\frac{1}{m_1} + ( \boldsymbol{n}\times \boldsymbol{d}_1) \cdot {\bf I}_1^{-1} (\boldsymbol{n} \times \boldsymbol{d}_1) + \frac{1}{m_2} + ( \boldsymbol{n}\times \boldsymbol{d}_2) \cdot {\bf I}_2^{-1} (\boldsymbol{n} \times \boldsymbol{d}_2)} $$

The above is the same you will find in the [Collision Response](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collision_response) Wikipedia article, as equation (5).

<sub>Note that $\times$ is the vector cross product, and $\cdot$ is the vector dot product.</sub>

It is also identical to equation (8-18) in the [Physically Based Modeling, Lecture Notes II](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/%7Ebaraff/sigcourse/notesd2.pdf#page=17) for rigid body simulations by Andrew Witkin and David Baraff. [SIGCOURSE link](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/%7Ebaraff/sigcourse/)

[image: fig1]

The exact calculation for $v_{\rm imp}$ is

$$ v_{\rm imp} =  \boldsymbol{n} \cdot ( \left(\boldsymbol{v}_1 + \boldsymbol{d}_1 \times \boldsymbol{\omega}_1\right) - \left( \boldsymbol{v}_2 + \boldsymbol{d}_2 \times \boldsymbol{\omega}_2 \right) ) $$

The above-calculated impulse $J$ obeys the law of contact

$$ v_{\rm bounce} = -\epsilon \; v_{\rm imp} $$

Here is an example implementation of the above calculation for two bodies in `C#`

```
public class Contact
{
    public Vector3 Position { get; set; }
    public Vector3 Normal { get; set; }
    public double Epsilon { get; set; }

    public double GetImpulse(RigidBody2 target, RigidBody2 contact, out double impactSpeed)
    {
        double m_1 = target.MassProperties.Mass;
        double m_2 = contact.MassProperties.Mass;
        Matrix3 I_1_inv = LinearAlgebra.Inverse(target.MassProperties.MMoi);
        Matrix3 I_2_inv = LinearAlgebra.Inverse(contact.MassProperties.MMoi);
        Vector3 d_1 = target.MassProperties.CG - Position;
        Vector3 d_2 = contact.MassProperties.CG - Position;
    
        Vector3 h_1 = LinearAlgebra.Cross(Normal, d_1);
        Vector3 h_2 = LinearAlgebra.Cross(Normal, d_2);
    
        double m_reduced = 1 / (
              1 / m_1 + LinearAlgebra.Dot(h_1, I_1_inv*h_1)
            + 1 / m_2 + LinearAlgebra.Dot(h_2, I_2_inv*h_2));
    
        impactSpeed = LinearAlgebra.Dot(Normal, 
             (contact.Velocity + LinearAlgebra.Cross(d_1, contact.Omega)) 
           - (target.Velocity) + LinearAlgebra.Cross(d_2, target.Omega));
    
        return (1 + Epsilon) * m_reduced * impactSpeed;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\b}  {\mathbf}$
Assume two particle collied in 3D

the equations are

\begin{align*}
 &m_1\,(\mathbf v_1-\mathbf u_1)=-\lambda\,\mathbf n\tag 1
 \end{align*}
\begin{align*}
  &m_2\,(\mathbf v_2-\mathbf u_2)=\lambda\,\mathbf n\tag 2
  \end{align*}
\begin{align*}
  &\left[(\mathbf v_2-\mathbf{v}_1)+\epsilon\,(\mathbf u_2-\mathbf u_1)\right]\cdot\mathbf n=0\tag 3
\end{align*}
you have 7 scalar equations for the 7 unknowns;  the  6 components of the vectors $~\mathbf v_i~$ and $~\lambda$

Adding equation (1) and (2) you obtain the conservation of the linear momentum and for $~\epsilon=1~$ the conservation of the energy .

where

- $\b v_1~,\b v_2~$ velocity after the collision
- $\b u_1~,\b u_2~$ velocity bevor the collision
- $m_i~$ particle masses
- $\b n~$ collision direction vector $\quad,\b n\cdot\b n=1$
- $\epsilon~$ coefficient of restitution
  $\quad,\epsilon=0~$ perfectly inelastic collision
  $\quad,\epsilon=1~$ perfectly elastic collision

---

**Theory**

starting with Newton equation immediately after the collision

\begin{align*}
 &m_i\,\frac{d\mathbf v'_i}{dt}= \pm\, F_c\,\mathbf n\quad\Rightarrow\\
 &m_i\,\int_{\mathbf u_i}^{\mathbf v_i}\,d\b v'_i=\pm\int  F_c\,\mathbf n\,dt=-\lambda\mathbf{n}
 \end{align*}
\begin{align*}
 &m_i\,(\mathbf v_i-\mathbf u_i)=\pm\lambda\,\mathbf n\quad i=1,2
\end{align*}
$~i=1~$ minus ,   $~i=2~$ plus

where $~ F_c~$ is the constraint force

**Conservation of the energy**

\begin{align*}
  &E=\frac{1}{2}\left(m_1\,(\mathbf{v}_1)^2+m_2\,(\mathbf{v}_2)^2-
  m_1\,(\mathbf{u}_1)^2-m_2\,(\mathbf{u}_2)^2\right)=0\\
  &2\,E=\left(m_1\,\left [(\mathbf{v}_1)^2- (\mathbf{u}_1)^2\right]
  +m_2\,\left[(\mathbf{v}_2)^2-
 (\mathbf{u}_2)^2\right]\right)=0\\
  &2\,E=\left(m_1\,\left [\mathbf{v}_1- \mathbf{u}_1\right]\cdot
  \left [\mathbf{v}_1+ \mathbf{u}_1\right]
  +m_2\,\left[\mathbf{v}_2-\mathbf{u}_2\right]
  \cdot \left[\mathbf{v}_2+\mathbf{u}_2\right]\right)=0\\
  &\text{with}\quad \mathbf{v}_1- \mathbf{u}_1=-\frac{\lambda}{m_1}\,\mathbf n
  \quad, \mathbf{v}_2- \mathbf{u}_2=\frac{\lambda}{m_2}\,\mathbf n\\
  &2\,E=\left(m_1\,\left [-\frac{\lambda}{m_1}\,\mathbf n\right]\cdot
  \left [\mathbf{v}_1+ \mathbf{u}_1\right]
  +m_2\,\left[\frac{\lambda}{m_2}\,\mathbf n\right]
  \cdot \left[\mathbf{v}_2+\mathbf{u}_2\right]\right)=0\quad\Rightarrow\\
  &2E=\left[(\mathbf v_2-\mathbf{v}_1)+(\mathbf u_2-\mathbf u_1)\right]\cdot\mathbf n=0
 \end{align*}
and  with the coefficient of restitution $~\epsilon~$
\begin{align*}
  &\left[(\mathbf v_2-\mathbf{v}_1)+\epsilon\,(\mathbf u_2-\mathbf u_1)\right]\cdot\mathbf n=0
 \end{align*}

thus for $~\epsilon=1~$ you obtain the conservation of the energy

---

**Example**

assume one dimensional

$$\b u_1=[u,0,0]^T~,\b u_2=[0,0,0]^T~,\b n=[1,0,0]^T$$

you obtain

$$\b v_1=\left[{\frac {u \left( m_{{1}}+m_{{2}}\epsilon  \right) }{m_{{2}}+m_{{1}}}}~,0~,0]^t\right]$$
$$\b v_2=\left[-{\frac {m_{{1}}u \left( -1+\epsilon  \right) }{m_{{2}}+m_{{1}}}}~,0~,0\right]^T$$
$$\lambda=-{\frac {m_{{2}}m_{{1}}u \left( -1+\epsilon  \right) }{m_{{2}}+m_{{1}}
}}
$$
$$2\,E={\frac {m_{{1}}{u}^{2}m_{{2}} \left( -1+{\epsilon }^{2} \right) }{m_{{
2}}+m_{{1}}}}
$$

Comment: How would this extend to rigid bodies though vs particles?

Comment: I assumed no rotation , the particles inertia are zero

Comment: How would this last derivation work with the coefficient of restitution? I believe that the energy equation becomes $\tfrac 1 2(m_1 v_1^2+m_2 v_2^2)=\tfrac 1 2 \epsilon^2(m_1 u_1^2+m_2 u_2^2)$. After factoring this becomes $m_1(v_1+\epsilon u_1)(v_1-\epsilon u_1)+m_2(v_2+\epsilon u_2)(v_2-\epsilon u_2)=0$, but this means we can no longer substitute equation (1).

Comment: After factoring the conservation of the energy, I use the definition of the coefficient of restitution. You can apply those three equations with arbitrary coefficient of restitution , the result that you obtain for the energy, is well known from the literature, so I think the equations are correct