# Finding motion for an off-center collision of two bodies that can both translate and rotate

Tags: kinematics, rotational-dynamics, collision

I am writing a simple physics simulation of a real-life problem, and am having trouble coming up with a closed-form solution.

#### Problem description

Two rigid bodies with specified masses $m_1$, $m_2$ and moments of inertia $I_1$, $I_2$ are tied together and compress a spring with stored energy $E$. These bodies are initially at rest and lying on a frictionless surface. At a certain time, the line connecting the bodies is cut, and the spring pushes the two bodies apart such that they slide and rotate on the surface. Note that the spring is not permanently attached, so there is no restoring force.

If the spring acts along a line of action with orthogonal distances $r_1$, $r_2$ to each body’s center of mass, then find the resulting velocities $v_1$, $v_2$ and rates of rotation $ω_1$, $ω_2$ for each body.

Here is a top view of this setup:

[image: sketch of scenario]

#### Current approach

This is essentially equivalent to an super-elastic collision problem, with a non-zero energy loss (gain) at the moment of impact. However, I cannot find example of this problem where one of the bodies is not a ball or point mass (which results in one known $ω = 0$, making for three unknowns).

In this case, I have four unknowns: $v_1$, $v_2$, $ω_1$, $ω_2$. I currently have three constraining equations: energy conservation, angular momentum conservation, and linear momentum conservation:

$$E = \frac{1}{2}m_1v_1^2 + \frac{1}{2}m_2v_2^2 + \frac{1}{2}I_1ω_1^2 + \frac{1}{2}I_2ω_2^2,$$
$$L = 0 = m_1v_1r_1 + m_2v_2r_2 + I_1ω_1 + I_2ω_2,$$
$$P = 0 = m_1v_1 + m_2v_2.$$

However, I’m lost as to finding a fourth constraining equation. This seems to me like it *should* have a closed form solution, does it?

Comment: What are the initial conditions?

Comment: The two bodies are initially at rest in my case.

Comment: so how they collied ?. you need at liest one initial  velocity

Comment: Not needed. The impulse is coming from the spring and not initial momentum. This problem is analogous to a collision and not a collision in a "true" sense.

Comment: So the spring  force cause initial velocity  and initial angular velocity of the bodies  ?

Comment: Initial velocities and angular velocities are 0. Final velocities and angular velocities are generated from the energy in the spring.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Collision with extended bodies](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/743864/collision-with-extended-bodies)

Comment: Here is a 3D example: https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/744811/392

Comment: That does help, thank you @John!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's choose our origin to be at a fixed point on the table somewhere along the line of application of the force.  The torque on each block about this origin is zero when the spring expands, since $\vec{\tau} = \vec{r} \times \vec{F}$ and $\vec{r}$ is parallel to $\vec{F}$ when $\vec{r}$ is measured about this origin.  Thus, the net angular momentum of each block (as measured with respect to this origin) is *independently* zero:
$$
\vec{L}_1 = \vec{L}_2 = 0 \quad \Rightarrow \quad m_1v_1r_1  + I_1ω_1 = m_2v_2r_2 + I_2ω_2 = 0.
$$
This is obviously a stronger condition on the angular momentum than you had ($\vec{L}_1 + \vec{L}_2 = 0$), and gives you an extra condition on the parameters that should allow you to solve for the final state.

---

Alternately, we can derive the same condition by considering the center of mass as our origin for the torque.  Let's assume that the force $\vec{F}_1$ is applied at a constant $\vec{r}_1$ relative to the center of mass (i.e., something like a quick, sharp hammer blow.)  Then the torque about the CM is $\vec{\tau}_1 = \vec{r}_1 \times \vec{F}_1$, and the total change in angular momentum of block 1 is
$$
\Delta \vec{L}_1 = \int \tau_1 \, dt  = \int \vec{r}_1 \times \vec{F}_1 \, dt = \vec{r}_1 \times \left[ \int \vec{F}_1 \, dt \right] 
$$
But the quantity in square brackets here is just the total impulse delivered to the block, and so we have
$$
\Delta \vec{L}_1 = \vec{r}_1 \times (\Delta \vec{p}_1)
$$
If you carefully keep track of the signs of the vectors and their components, this eventually reduces to
$$
- I \omega_1 = m_1 r_1 v_1
$$
as found above;  and the same argument applies to block 2 as well.

Comment: That would give that extra equation, but I'm not sure I'm following your train of logic. We can choose an arbitrary origin to measure angular momentum about, but for torque, $\bar r$ necessarily points from the line of action to the center of mass, so there is no way here for that to be parallel to $\bar F$.

Comment: And so I'm not seeing how the bodies independently having 0 angular momentum follows.

Comment: @Scott:  Torque can be measured with respect to any origin, not just with respect to the center of mass;  and for any fixed origin, $\vec{\tau} = d\vec{L}/dt$.  It's also true that with respect to any fixed origin, $\vec{L} = m \vec{r} \times \vec{v} + \vec{L}_{cm}$ (you used this fact yourself in your derivation, I believe.)  The original derivation follows from those facts.  That said, it's also possible to derive this result by considering the torque about the center of mass;  I've added a demonstration of how the argument works in that case.

Comment: Thank you @Micheal, that clears it up for me. Appreciate the help!