# Rods collision, determine angular velocity and velocity

Tags: classical-mechanics, collision

[image: collision]

The rods are moving twards each other in a velocity v1, and v2.

Assuming it will be a elastic collision, after it, how would I determine the velocity of the mass center of both bodies, and how would I determine the angular velocity of both bodies?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: In addition to linear momentum and kinetic energy being conserved (for an elastic collision) for the two-rod system, angular momentum of the two-rod system is also conserved since there are no external torques. There is insufficient information to do the evaluation; for example, what is the distance of overlap of the rods at impact?

Comment: Also read about [the general 3D collision problem](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/744811/392).